# Iphone web application

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I am developing a iphone web application. I already have a website designed using php and mysql. how I can convert this website to compatile for iphone.

pls share your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's specifically designed for the iPhone, then you can simply load it up onto one and develop accordingly. If your site is primarily desktop oriented, then you could:

1. **Do nothing.** The iPhone is designed for non-iPhone-aware web sites, and so your's will probably work just like that. In practice a little tweaking will probably make things much better.
2. **Build a parallel site,** custom-made for the iPhone, and use browser-detection to redirect to that site when an iPhone comes knocking.